# Collect results from Distributed tests JMeter java code

Tags: java, jmeter

I am trying to create Distributed tests using JMeter in java ( no GUI no command line )

In my code i use:

```
    List<String> addresses = Arrays.asList("address1","address2");
    HashTree tree = new HashTree();

    DistributedRunner dRunner = new DistributedRunner();

    dRunner.init(addresses,tree);
    dRunner.start();
```

The Server instances are already set up ( listening on address1 and so on ). However i cannot find an optimal way how to collect result from the server instances. Is there a way how to do so? Typically, master/slave have bidirectional communication, but this seems like the master sends command to execute test to slaves but slaves does not return result to master.

What is the correct way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What [test plan](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JmxTestPlan) you're running? Empty? If this is the case you should not get any results.

If there is some initialization code behind it you need to update your question with this code as it should be sufficient to define the [.jtl result file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JtlFiles) and your master machine will collect the results from the slaves.

Example snippet, put it before `dRunner.init(addresses,tree);` line:

```
Summariser summer = null;
String summariserName = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("summariser.name", "summary");
if (summariserName.length() > 0) {
    summer = new Summariser(summariserName);
}


String logFile = "/path/to/result.jtl";
ResultCollector logger = new ResultCollector(summer);
logger.setFilename(logFile);
tree.add(testPlanTree.getArray()[0], logger);
```

That would be the equivalent of providing the result file location via [`-t` command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) otherwise the test will be started but the results will be going nowhere

More information and useful code snippets:

- [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui)
- [jmeter-from-code](https://bitbucket.org/blazemeter/jmeter-from-code/) repo

Comment: Thanks for answers, so the solution is to define jtl file with result in slave machines and let master machine to collect it with ResultCollector? I assume "path/to/result.jtl" must be the same on every slave machine? Also What is testPlanTree in your example? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Johnyb, did you get the answer to the above question, how did you fix it, When i included the above snippet code before dRunner.init(addresses,tree); , the results are collecting in my case. please help ...

Comment: @MohasinAli i did, i fixed it. Needed to set mode=Standard